# How to draw an rectangle on a side of a triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a side like this picture.
[image]

I tried

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round;]
    \path 
    (0,0) coordinate (A)
(3,0) coordinate (B)
(0,2) coordinate (C)    
    ;
    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle
 (B) --(5,0) ;
\foreach \p/\g in {A/-90,B/-90,C/90}
\path (\p)+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$};
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

and get

[image]

Comment: `\draw (A) -- (B) -- node[at end, sloped, above right, draw, outer sep=0pt] {$m$} (C) -- cycle;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate the `\draw` adding the option:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round;]
\path (0,0) coordinate (A)
      (3,0) coordinate (B)
      (0,2) coordinate (C);
\draw (5,0) -- (A) node[below] {$A$} -- (C) node[above] {$C$} -- (B) node[below] {$B$};
\draw[rotate={-atan(2/3)},transform shape] (C) rectangle ++ (1,0.8) node[midway] {$m$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]